# In dally gem, "socket_max_failures" options in not working for write and read operations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, memcached, dalli

I am using dalli 2.7.0.

I faced a problem where the memcache instance became unreachable. When a set request was triggered, it should have timed out in 0.5 seconds (the default timeout), instead the dalli client kept retrying.

On further investigation I found that the failure count is reset on every retry.

Trace :

1. lib/dalli/server.rb : method write : line 532 - The @sock.write times out.
2. lib/dalli/server.rb : method failure! : line 209 - The @fail_count is incremented
3. lib/dalli/server.rb : method failure! : line 215 - Dalli::NetworkError is raised
4. lib/dalli/client.rb : method perform : line 328 - The transaction is retried
5. lib/dalli/ring.rb : method server_for_key : line 36 - Server's availability is checked.
6. lib/dalli/server.rb : method up! : line 243 - The @fail_count is reset.

The loop continues. Am I missing some config or is there a bug in the dalli code. 
Can you guys help me figure it out.

Comment: Do you have memcached at least version 1.4 installed? If yes, can you also post the debug logs that Dalli produces during the reconnects?

Comment: @BoraMa : I am using memcache VERSION 1.4.13.
Dalli log :
Dalli::Server#connect services:11211
services:11211 failed (count: 0) Timeout::Error: IO timeout: {:host=>"services", :port=>11211, :down_retry_delay=>1, :socket_timeout=>0.0005, :socket_max_failures=>2, :socket_failure_delay=>0.01, :value_max_bytes=>1048576, :compressor=>Dalli::Compressor, :compression_min_size=>1024, :compression_max_size=>false, :serializer=>Marshal, :username=>nil, :password=>nil, :keepalive=>true}
#<Dalli::NetworkError: Socket operation failed, retrying...>

The above log line repeats. Failed count is 0 always.

Comment: Is the reconnect behavior the same if you increase the `socket_timeout`? Your current value of 0.0005, which means 0.5 microseconds seems insanely low to me. The default is 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Yes...the reconnect behaviour is same even 0.5 seconds as well. I faced the problem with the default setting in my production and then started looking into this issue.

Comment: Can you raise the logging level to `:debug` and post all the Dalli-related log messages? Also I would try if the behavior persists with the newest version of Dalli (2.7.6).

Comment: The logs are with logging level set to :debug. I have checked that the issue is in dally 2.7.6 as well. I made the following change in the gem to fix the issue : https://github.com/Tholkappiyan/dalli/commit/745fbb6a059651f67762dc2765a3eb7841ebc1f6. I tested the fix for 'set' but yet to test the fix for 'get'.